# Centered div locked in place, can't move up or down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay so I have a simple website with a big 100px H1 header centered at the top, and I have an h2 and a paragraph below that, both centered.

Those are all lining up nicely.

Problem is, the h2 and p are inside a div that is transparent black to allow for easy reading against the background, and it's a bit too far down from the h1 heading. The div itself is locked in place, and the h2 and p are inside the div of course. I'm wanting to move the div up a bit, but no matter how I change the top attribute it will not move.

*note: the h1 is not inside a div at all, nor is it inside of a header tag. It's just in the body tag.

I have researched this a fair bit, and some have told me to change the position of the div that is locked in place to absolute or relative, but all that seems to do is make the div and everything inside of it not centered anymore, and it is still otherwise locked in place. The code for the website is a bit long, so I will include the html layout and the css for every element involved in the issue. If you need more to help me out, just let me know :)

html:

```
<body class="home-page">
    <h1>Visit Montana</h1>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="home.html">
            <button id="home">
                home
            </button>
        </a>
        <a href="dining.html">
            <button id="dining">
                dining
            </button>
        </a>
        <a href="entertainment.html">
            <button id="entertainment">
                entertainment
            </button>
        </a>
        <a href="lodging.html">
            <button id="lodging">
                lodging
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="main-body">
        <h2>
            Why Visit Montana?
        </h2>
        <p>
            words (I modified this so it wouldn't be a wall of text. There     are 200 words here)
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
h1{
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
        position:relative;
        font-size:100px;
        font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
        padding:0;
        z-index:6;      
    }

h2{
        font-size:50px;
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
         position:relative;
        font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
        padding:20px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

p{
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:left;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
    padding:0px 40px 0px 40px;
}

.main-body{
    background-color:rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.57);
    height:425px;
    width:1100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, I'm brand new here and I'm not familiar with what you're asking me to do.. Are you saying I should post this on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: its ok, you got a answer from ketan. check if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should remove all default padding and margin of browser. Use following for that.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and then you can give `margin-top` to `.main-body` div to move them up and down.

```
.main-body {
    background-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.57);
    height: 425px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px; //Here.
    width: 1100px;
}
```

Here i give `margin-top:20px`. You can change it as per your requirement.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5dn028c/)**

Comment: wow, I feel like an idiot I was literally just using a top attribute to try and move this up and down, instead of the margin-top attribute. Oddly enough this has worked in the past and I'm curious as to how this situation is different. 

Thanks for the quick answer, I really appreciate it